# wpf - transparent MainWindow and issues with DragMove "Can only call DragMove when primary mouse button is down."

Tags: transparency, mainwindow, mouseleftbuttondown

I have a wpf project which uses transparent windows and I share this transparent window styling for my dialog windows and my `mainwindow`.

I am getting an error on my `DragMove()` event of my `MainWindow` AFTER I close a dialog window that uses the same window style. To make this even more strange this exception only occurs when I handle a `mouseleftbutton` event on a label in my `Status Bar` on the `MainWindow`.  IF I swap out the label for a button and replace the `mouseleftbuttondown` with a `click` event I do not get the error.

The strange thing is that the dialog window that pops up does not implement `dragmove`, and I'm not dragging around my `mainwindow` either. Somehow `dragmove` gets called after my code execution returns to the `mainwindow` after a `showdialog()` call.

An easy fix for me currently is to swap my label for a button and wire up the click event instead.

However, I'm more interested in hearing about what causes this issue and why a click event works but the mouse one fails miserably.

My "StatusBar" is simply a `stackpanel` with labels and other stackpanels (which contain more labels).

Has anyone else fought this issue before? Would I need to implement some sort of `mouseclick` event handler override so that I can capture and cancel this exception from happening?

Repro code can be provided if needed. I got enough hits on `dragmove` here so I am hoping this is an easy one for somebody out there.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my brain isn't working properly today. I forgot about routing of events in this scenario. I simply needed to set the Handled property on my routedevent that fired off when the mousebutton was down.  Somehow I missed that in the debugger before posting the thread.

Answer (score 2):

The 'correct' way to make a borderless window movable --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275712/146032

Be sure to only call DragMove when triggered by event MouseLeftButtonDown and don't forget to handle the event using e.Handled=true;

Comment: That's a good link but it doesn't have anything to do with my issue here. I had a runaway bubble event that was throwing it all out of whack. My dialog that popped up didn't even implement dragmove so there was no way to drag it around.

Answer (score 1):

if you receive this exception when messagebox show complete. place Dragemove();
inside try and empty in catch.